# What determines how much RAM textures take up?

Tags: android, memory-management, libgdx, textures

Does this depend on the physical size of the texture or something else?

Let's say I have two empty textures:

- Texture1 - 1KB, 1024x1024
- Texture2 - 1KB, 32x32

Will they take up the same amount of RAM?

Comment: Once in memory, the first one will take more than 4MB. The latter, 4K. The formula is : **X * Y * 4**

Comment: Could the people who downvoted the question give specific reasons? I'd say this is a good question (apart from the formatting).

Answer (score 1):

A texture is practically an array of `texture pixel`.

If you've a texture of dimension `1024 x 1024` means total 1048576 `texture pixel` . Each one unit is represented by a color with a `red`, `green`, `blue` and `alpha` component, where each component is one byte so size required to store that texture is `1048576*4=4194304` bytes in size (which is 4MB).

```
Texture on disk (in any compressed form like png..) 
   |
   V
Decompressed When loaded into Memory(RAM) by <-> CPU 
   |
   V
Rendering is done by GPU so texture array need to be in copied to VRAM
```

---

Single amount of RAM or same amount in RAM ?

No different size in RAM.

Comment: Textures can be loaded at depths other than RGBA8888, and they can be loaded with ETC1 compression, so it is not necessarily 4 bytes per pixel.